# how to stop cursor jumping of a controlled input

Tags: reactjs, input

i'm currently using react-phone-input-2 as Formik Field , but i try to edit the phone number the cursor jumps to the end. this my cellphone component.

```
 const Telephone = (props) => {
  const { form = {}, ...others } = props;
  const { setTouched, setFieldValue } = form;
  return <PhoneInput
    specialLabel=''
    enableSearch
    searchNotFound=""
    localization={fr}
    onBlur={() => setTouched && setTouched({ [name]: true })}
    onChange={val => setFieldValue(name, val)}
    isValid={!error}
    value={field.value}
    preferredCountries={['fr']}
    {...props}
  />
```

if there's anyone who is struggled with this problem and fixed it, I'll be thankful if you can share with me your solution.